# How to update selenium-webdriver's version?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using Protractor `5.4.2`. How do I update to the latest available `selenium-webdriver` version, i.e. `4.0.0-alpha-5`.

Comment: have you tried `webdriver-manager update` ?

Comment: @JoaquinCasco I have. `webdriver-manage update` only updates to default version; 3.6.0 as per protractor/node_modules/selenium_webdriver/package.json

How do I update selenium-webdriver within Protractor to the latest version?

Comment: could you provide your package.json scripts @Digitful

Answer (score 1):

You can install 4.0.0-alpha.5 directly with the following command

> npm i selenium-webdriver

But I would not recommend you to update alone selenium-webdriver because something may break.

Answer (score 0):

For Maven as build automation tool in your project you can simply add in your pom:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can have a look: [dependencies build tool](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.0.0-alpha-4/jar)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Maven or any external build tools are, however, out of scope. We're strictly working with Protractor `5.4.2` only.